# Exporting to XLSX from my server returns "Failed - Server issue"

Tags: laravel-4, phpexcel

I have laravel in my server side, and im using PHPEXCEL to export .xlsx to my computer, problem is, and it's only in the server (in localhost, same code, all is fine).

This is the code that excute the export:

```
  Excel::create('survey result', function($excel) use ($arrayToExport){

        // Todo: Survey Results' - survey->name;
        $excel->setTitle('Survey Results');

        $excel->setCreator('mrSurvey')->setCompany('mrSurvey');
        $excel->setDescription('Survey results');


          $excel->sheet('First sheet', function($sheet) use($arrayToExport) {
                  $sheet->fromArray(

                     $arrayToExport
                  ,null,'A1',false,false);

          });

    })->export('xlsx');
}
```

Now if i change that to xls it all works fine, but i need the xlsx type...What can be the cause to a problem named: "Failed - Server problem"

Comment: PHPExcel requires a lot of memory - check your server logs.

Comment: I cant see any server problems in the error log, and if it was phpexcel, why the xls is working? any other suggestions? using cpanel, i did even the htaccess changes that was needed to allow export/import of xlsx and still error, No idea what the problem...any needed extensions are in order?

Comment: Another thing i need to mention is this: even a small file, like 2 rows and 2 columns, it wont let me download xlsx